# javascript string handling with array why it's print 'r' on console but not 'z'

Tags: javascript

```
var cun = function(cun){
    cun[0] = 'z';
    console.log(cun[0]);
    return cun;
}
cun("ratul");
```

Why it is print r on console but not z ? why i can't change the string using array notation?

Answer (score 3):

Strings are immutable. You cannot change them. You have to create a new string for that.

```
function cun(str) {
    var newString = 'z' + str.substring(1);
    console.log( newString[0] );
    return newString;
}

cun('ratul');
```

Answer (score 2):

Because strings are immutable (meaning you can't change their value) in JavaScript.

You can accomplish what you are trying to do a variety of ways, including:

```
var cun = function(cun){
    return "z" + cun.slice(1);
}
cun("ratul");
```

Answer (score 0):

from the [rhino book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596000486/):

> In JavaScript, strings are immutable objects, which means that the
>   characters within them may not be changed and that any operations on
>   strings actually create new strings. Strings are assigned by
>   reference, not by value. In general, when an object is assigned by
>   reference, a change made to the object through one reference will be
>   visible through all other references to the object. Because strings
>   cannot be changed, however, you can have multiple references to a
>   string object and not worry that the string value will change without
>   your knowing it

You can try:

```
String.prototype.replaceAt=function(index, character) {
   return this.substr(0, index) + character + this.substr(index+character.length);
}
var hello="ratul";
alert(hello.replaceAt(0, "z"));
```

[Here is working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8M9ku/)

Comment: `a change made to the object through one reference will be visible through all other references` Not true. Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JdW6m/

Comment: but I never say it will change..... :( last sentence is `however, you can have multiple references to a string object and not worry that the string value will change without your knowing it`

Comment: Look at my fiddle. `a` was `'hello'` and `b` was set to `a` I changed `a`, so `b` should change as well, according to your quote, but it doesn't.

Comment: I quote `strings are immutable objects` the important part there is **objects**

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38476/discussion-between-zaheer-ahmed-and-joe-simmons)